# ftp mput sends only four file - ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I wrote a bash script and i am running it with cron in ubuntu 12.04 for every minute.

Here below you can see my ftp upload script:

```
#!/bin/sh 
HOST='192.168.10.40' 
USER='user1' 
PASSWD='Oo123456' 
FILE='CAM_1_*'
DIR='SecImg' 
UP='..' 
cd  /home/user1/Masaüstü/BBTCP/
chmod 777 $FILE
ftp -v -n $HOST <<__END_OF_SESSION
user $USER $PASSWD 
type binary 
cd $DIR 
mput $FILE
cd $UP 
bye 
__END_OF_SESSION
```

In the directory there are 10 different files named in the format CAM_1_IP_EPOCH.jpg

For example

CAM_1_192.168.10.30_12345678.jpg

CAM_1_192.168.10.30_12345688.jpg

CAM_1_192.168.10.30_12345698.jpg

...

CAM_1_192.168.10.30_12345878.jpg

But mput only sends 4 files. How can I send all files over ftp.

When I try to send here is the output:

Here is the output:

```
Connected to 192.168.10.40.
220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
331 Password required for ozen.ozkaya
230 Logged on
Remote system type is UNIX.
?Invalid command
200 Type set to I
250 CWD successful. "/SecImg" is current directory.
mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750625.jpg? 200 Port command successful
150 Opening data channel for file transfer.
226 Transfer OK
14682 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (5206.2 kB/s)
mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750628.jpg? 200 Port command successful
150 Opening data channel for file transfer.
226 Transfer OK
14636 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (4809.2 kB/s)
mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750631.jpg? 200 Port command successful
150 Opening data channel for file transfer.
226 Transfer OK
14872 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (5260.2 kB/s)
mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750635.jpg? 200 Port command successful
150 Opening data channel for file transfer.
226 Transfer OK
14569 bytes sent in 0.00 secs (4850.8 kB/s)
mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750638.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750640.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750644.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750647.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750650.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750654.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750658.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750660.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750694.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750696.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750699.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750703.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750706.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750709.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750713.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750716.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750719.jpg? mput CAM_1_192.168.10.33_1339750723.jpg? 221 Goodbye
```

It only sends first four and can not send the rest...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what's happening is bash is expanding the FILE='CAM_1_*' into a full list of files on your local system, and then the mput command line is too long to process all the files.

Try adding an 'echo ${FILE} line after setting FILE to see what value the variable has.

If this is happening, then add a 'set -f' command before setting FILE to disable the filename expansion.

Comment: It can find files but can not send.

I added the output to question

Comment: Do the unent files already exist on the remote system, possibly with file permissions or ownership which would keep them from being overwritten by ftp ?

Also you may want to try including the '-i' flag in the ftp call to turn off interactive prompting during multiple file transfers.  

Also the '?Invalid Command' output around the 'type binary' looks weird.  Maybe just try 'binary'.